# in django admin model listing, Display 'Yes/No' for method's return value

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am learning django admin on dJango project site, and I want to display 'Yes/No' instead of True/False icons in admin listing page. These values come from a method defined in AdminModel.

There is a method in a model class that returns True/False. in django there is an attribute "boolean", when assigned "True", it show red & green icons for column on admin listing page.

```py
**class** Question(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        **return** now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to write a custom method for that:

```
class QuestionAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_dipslay = [..., 'recently_published']
    readonly_fields = [..., 'recently_published']
    # ...
    def recently_published(self, obj):
        return ('No', 'Yes')[obj.was_published_recently()]
    recently_published.short_description = 'whatever column header'
```

To my knowledge, there are no convenient hooks to change the boolean fields list display behaviour globally.